# Django/Wagtail : InvalidFilterSpecError at /blog/article-blog-page/ when i refresh my Article Blog Page

Tags: python, django, wagtail

While following the tutorial from [Wagtail CMS: How to subclass Wagtail Pages](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Tg0wAvr7U4) , i got into an error while refreshing my article blog page. I am using Debug Toolbar   3.2.2, Python       3.9.6, Wagtail core 2.14.1, Taggit  1.5.1 and Django Extensions 3.1.3.

Error code:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/article-blog-page/

Django Version: 3.2.7
Python Version: 3.9.6
Installed Applications:
['home',
 'search',
 'flex',
 'streams',
 'site_settings',
 'subscribers',
 'blog',
 'wagtail.contrib.forms',
 'wagtail.contrib.redirects',
 'wagtail.contrib.settings',
 'wagtail.contrib.routable_page',
 'wagtail.contrib.sitemaps',
 'wagtail.contrib.modeladmin',
 'wagtail.embeds',
 'wagtail.sites',
 'wagtail.users',
 'wagtail.snippets',
 'wagtail.documents',
 'wagtail.images',
 'wagtail.search',
 'wagtail.admin',
 'wagtail.core',
 'modelcluster',
 'taggit',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.sitemaps',
 'debug_toolbar',
 'django_extensions']
Installed Middleware:
['django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'wagtail.contrib.redirects.middleware.RedirectMiddleware',
 'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware']


Template error:
In template C:\Users\pedro.garcia\website\mysite\mysite\templates\base.html, error at line 35
   construct() missing 1 required positional argument: 'size'
   25 :         {% block extra_css %}
   26 :             {# Override this in templates to add extra stylesheets #}
   27 :         {% endblock %}
   28 :     </head>
   29 : 
   30 :     <body class="{% block body_class %}{% endblock %}">
   31 :         {% wagtailuserbar %}
   32 :         <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
   33 :         <div class="container-fluid">
   34 :             <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Sesacre</a>
   35 :             <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarColor02" aria-controls="navbarCo lor02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigat ion">
   36 :             <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
   37 :             </button>
   38 : 
   39 :             <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarColor02">
   40 :             
   41 :             <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto">
   42 :                 <li class="nav-item">
   43 :                 <a class="nav-link active" href="/">início
   44 :                     <span class="visually-hidden">(current)</span>
   45 :                 </a>


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\pedro.garcia\.virtualenvs\mysite-BGHBG09T\lib\site-packages\wagtail\images\image_operations.py", line 15, in __init__
    inspect.getcallargs(self.construct, *args)
  File "c:\users\pedro.garcia\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\inspect.py", line 1411, in getcallargs
    _missing_arguments(f_name, req, True, arg2value)
  File "c:\users\pedro.garcia\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\inspect.py", line 1340, in _missing_arguments
    raise TypeError("%s() missing %i required %s argument%s: %s" %

During handling of the above exception (construct() missing 1 required positional argument: 'size'), another exception occurred:
  File "C:\Users\pedro.garcia\.virtualenvs\mysite-BGHBG09T\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\pedro.garcia\.virtualenvs\mysite-BGHBG09T\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 204, in _get_response
    response = response.render()
  File "C:\Users\pedro.garcia\.virtualenvs\mysite-BGHBG09T\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py", line 105, in render
    self.content = self.rendered_content
  File "C:\Users\pedro.garcia\.virtualenvs\mysite-BGHBG09T\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py", line 83, in rendered_content
    return template.render(context, self._request)
  File "C:\Users\pedro.garcia\.virtualenvs\mysite-BGHBG09T\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\pedro.garcia\.virtualenvs\mysite-BGHBG09T\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 170, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "C:\Users\pedro.garcia\.virtualenvs\mysite-BGHBG09T\lib\site-packages\django\test\utils.py", line 100, in instrumented_test_render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\pedro.garcia\.virtualenvs\mysite-BGHBG09T\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\pedro.garcia\.virtualenvs\mysite-BGHBG09T\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\pedro.garcia\.virtualenvs\mysite-BGHBG09T\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "C:\Users\pedro.garcia\.virtualenvs\mysite-BGHBG09T\lib\site-packages\django\test\utils.py", line 100, in instrumented_test_render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\pedro.garcia\.virtualenvs\mysite-BGHBG09T\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\pedro.garcia\.virtualenvs\mysite-BGHBG09T\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\pedro.garcia\.virtualenvs\mysite-BGHBG09T\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 62, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\pedro.garcia\.virtualenvs\mysite-BGHBG09T\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\pedro.garcia\.virtualenvs\mysite-BGHBG09T\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\pedro.garcia\.virtualenvs\mysite-BGHBG09T\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 312, in render
    return nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\pedro.garcia\.virtualenvs\mysite-BGHBG09T\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\pedro.garcia\.virtualenvs\mysite-BGHBG09T\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\pedro.garcia\.virtualenvs\mysite-BGHBG09T\lib\site-packages\wagtail\images\templatetags\wagtailimages_tags.py", line 107, in render
    rendition = get_rendition_or_not_found(image, self.filter)
  File "C:\Users\pedro.garcia\.virtualenvs\mysite-BGHBG09T\lib\site-packages\wagtail\images\shortcuts.py", line 13, in get_rendition_or_not_found
    return image.get_rendition(specs)
  File "C:\Users\pedro.garcia\.virtualenvs\mysite-BGHBG09T\lib\site-packages\wagtail\images\models.py", line 281, in get_rendition
    cache_key = filter.get_cache_key(self)
  File "C:\Users\pedro.garcia\.virtualenvs\mysite-BGHBG09T\lib\site-packages\wagtail\images\models.py", line 480, in get_cache_key
    for operation in self.operations:
  File "C:\Users\pedro.garcia\.virtualenvs\mysite-BGHBG09T\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\pedro.garcia\.virtualenvs\mysite-BGHBG09T\lib\site-packages\wagtail\images\models.py", line 410, in operations
    operations.append(op_class(*op_spec_parts))
  File "C:\Users\pedro.garcia\.virtualenvs\mysite-BGHBG09T\lib\site-packages\wagtail\images\image_operations.py", line 17, in __init__
    raise InvalidFilterSpecError(e)

Exception Type: InvalidFilterSpecError at /blog/article-blog-page/
Exception Value: construct() missing 1 required positional argument: 'size'
```

if there is something more to add so i can help, please write it down

[image: Error picture]

EDIT 1: my *article_blog_page.html*:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load wagtailimages_tags wagtailcore_tags %}
{% block content %}
{% image self.banner_image fill-1200x300 as banner %}
<img src="{{ banner.url }}" alt="{{ banner.alt }}" style='width: 100%; height: auto;'>
<div class="container mt-5 mb-5">
    <div class="text-center">
        <h1>{% if self.custom_title %}{{ self.custom_title }}{% else %}{{ self.title }}{% endif %}</h1>
        {% if self.subtitle %}
        {% if self.categories.count %}
            <h3>{{ self.subtitle }}</h3>
        {% endif %}
        <div style="padding: 0 20px 20px">
            {% for cat in self.categories.all %}
            <a href="?category={{ cat.slug }}">
                {{ cat.name }}
            </a>{% if not forloop.last %}, {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
        {% endif %}
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
            {% for iter in self.blog_authors.all %}
            {% image iter.author.image fill-50x50 as img %}
            <div>
                <div>
                    <img src="{{ img.url }}" class="rounded-circle" alt="{{ iter.author.name }}">
                </div>
                {% if iter.author.website %}
                <a href="{{ iter.author.website }}">
                    {{ iter.author.name }}
                </a>
                {% else %}
                {{ iter.author.name }}
                {% endif %}
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

{% if self.intro_image %}
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-8 offset-lg-2"
                {% image self.intro_image fill 1400x400 as intro_img %}
                <img src="{{ intro_img.url }}" alt="{{ intro_img.alt }}">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endif %}

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 offset-lg-2">
            {% for block in self.content %}
            {% include_block block %}
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: This is probably coming from an {% image %} tag (most likely on line 35 of your blog page template - there's a known issue with Django's error reporting where it sometimes shows the wrong template file). Check that the syntax of that tag matches the documentation - if you're unsure, post that code here and we'll troubleshoot further.

Comment: @gasman i edited and added my article blog page template, i would really appreciate if you could look into it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{% image self.intro_image fill 1400x400 as intro_img %}
```

should be

```
{% image self.intro_image fill-1400x400 as intro_img %}
```

(note the `-` after 'fill', rather than the space)

Comment: indeed the " - " was missing and it was causing that error, thank you very much!!!